# Incremental addition of dictionary values to a pandas DataFrame. DataFrame with column names of dict keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, indexing, append

Suppose I have a dict and create a pandas DataFrame as

```
dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b','c'])
```

Every time I create a new dict with same keys I need to add the values as a row to `df`. Initially, `df` has no rows and no index assigned. What I am aware of is using

```
df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)
```

But, this keeps adding columns. Also, since dictionaries don't carry an order, would hard coding something like `list(dict.values())` randomize the order prior to inserting, the created list as a row to `df`, especially when I keep updating the `dict`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have data frames with same columns, you should consider using `concat`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

If you want to use append, supposing you have your `df` and a `values` dict:

```
values = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
df = df.append(pd.Series(values), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: `df.append(values, ignore_index=True)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

After creating your initial DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b','c'])
df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

You can then append dictionaries with matching columns. I would do this by passing a dictionary to the DataFrame constructor and using `pd.concat()` though there may be a more efficient/faster way:

```
from_dict = pd.DataFrame({k: [v] for (k, v) in dic.items()})
df = pd.concat([df, from_dict]) #default axis = 0
df
     a    b    c
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
```